# Will JPA generate more than one auto generated coulmns

Tags: spring-data-jpa

everyone I have a requirement that I want to generate two auto-generated values for two different columns. I am using Azure SQL DB as my RDBMS.

and I am using spring data JPA to persist my values.

Example:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_JUST_FOR_TEST")
public class TJustForTest implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SEQ_JUST_FOR_TEST", allocationSize=1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_GEN")
  private long id;

private String userRegistrationId; 

  public TJustForTest() {}

  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

here, I would like to use Id as my primary key as auto-generated and userRegistration Id also auto-generated but not primary key just a unique key and some custom format

Example
 I will append some string as prefix and id as a suffix, meaning I will use the same primary key to generate the userRegistration No.

is there any way to achieve this or any other way around it, please clarify.

Answer (score 0):

finally, I found a better solution to generate userRegistration by using Id,

I need to write one Listener class to get the auto-generated Id in my using @PostPersist
annotation, actually this will be called once the entity object persists in DB.

```
 public class TJustForTestListener {

    @PostPersist
        public void getPostPersist(TJustForTest ob) {
            try {
                ob.setuserRegistrationId("CR"+ob.getId());

            }catch(Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

and in Entity level i need to declare my listener class by using @EntityListeners

```
@Entity
@Table(name="T_JUST_FOR_TEST")
@EntityListeners(TJustForTestListener .class)
public class TJustForTest implements Serializable {
  private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

  @Id
  @SequenceGenerator(name="SEQ_GEN", sequenceName="SEQ_JUST_FOR_TEST", allocationSize=1)
  @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator="SEQ_GEN")
  private long id;

private String userRegistrationId; 

  public TJustForTest() {}

  public long getId() {
    return this.id;
  }

  public void setId(long id) {
    this.id = id;
  }
}
```

that's all it is required, JPA will insert the record first then update automatically.